# How to use WP Post Status Transitions to handle posts expiration dates

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time

I'm new at this & date/time/PHP thing just makes my brain hurt.

**1)** How to use [WP Post Status Transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) to register exact date & time of post status change (let's name it **valueX**)?

**2)** Now I bring other value from my theme options (**valueY**) - it's either a period (e.g 30 days) or date & time

**3)** How to make a calculation with **valueX** and **valueY** to get **valueZ** -> that's date & time when post changes to draft or deletes itself!

**How this should work in the end:**

1. I have 2 inputs in theme options, 1 is for draft lifespawn and 1 is for published post lifespawn (Input is int - value is either minutes or hours)
2. If you publish post, it saves date and time of this event.
3. Add theme options value (published post lifespawn int) to that time and outcome is the date post changes to draft
4. If that time comes, change post to draft (and save that time)
5. Add theme options value (draft lifespawn int) to that time and outcome is the date when draft gets deleted
6. Delete draft if that time comes

It all sounds so logical but I don't have enough skill to do this.

**My code:**

Note that:

- I separated it to 2 parts for easier reading - first is published post to draft and second code is
  draft to delete. Every step is commented.
- Logic is that if you edit published post, it shouldn't reset timer
  and if you change post to draft in any given time, it starts draft
  process and stops published post process.
- This seems to be way too long and complicated.. That's why I didn't
  add it in the first place. Im sure it could be done in much easier
  way.
- I used WP post time and edit time because I don't know how to save time
  & date of that certain time to separate value using [WP Post Status Transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions).

**PUBLISH -> DRAFT**

```
    if ( !function_exists('tt_icon_time_left') ) {
      function tt_icon_time_left() {

        //Set Timezone To Local
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

        // Check post status
        if ( get_post_status($post->ID) == "publish" ) {

          //Get Property Publish Date
          $time_post_published = get_the_time( 'H:i:s d.m.Y' );

          // Get Active Post Expiration Value From Theme Options
          global $theme_option;
          $post_time_integer = $theme_option['post-time-left'];

          // Get Active Post Expiration Value From Meta
          $single_post_time_left = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_time_left', true );

          // Decide If Theme Options Or Meta Active Post Expiration Value
          if ( $single_post_time_left <= 0 && $post_time_integer <= 0 ) {
            $post_time = 0;
          }
          else if ( $single_post_time_left < $post_time_integer && $single_post_time_left > 0 || $single_post_time_left > $post_time_integer ) {
            $post_time = $single_post_time_left;
          }
          else {
            $post_time = $post_time_integer;
          }

          // Active Post Expiration Value To Seconds
          $post_time_seconds = $post_time * 86400;

          // Active Post Age In Seconds
          $active_post_age = strtotime($time_post_published);
          $active_post_age = time() - $active_post_age;

          // Calculate Active Post Expiration Date
          $post_expiration_time = date( 'H:i:s d.m.Y' ,strtotime( $time_post_published ) + $post_time_seconds );

          // Show Icon And Time Left Until Active Post Changes To Draft In Tooltip ONLY SHOWN IN SUBMIT LISTING
          if ( $post_time > 0 && $active_post_age <= $post_time_seconds ) {
            global $post;
            if ( is_page_template( 'template-post-submit-listing.php' ) ) { 
              return '<i class="fa fa-clock-o" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . __( 'Post expires on ' .  $post_expiration_time, 'tt' ) . '"></i>'; 
            }
            else {
              return false;
            }
          }
```

**DRAFT -> DELETE**

```
          // Change Active Post To Draft If Time Is Up
          else if ( $post_time > 0 && $active_post_age > $post_time_seconds ) {
            $postt['post_status'] = 'draft';
            wp_update_post($post);
          }
          else {
           return false; 
          }
        }
        // Chech post status
        else if ( get_post_status($post->ID) == "draft" ) {

          $time_post_published = $publish_time;

          // Get Draft Expiration Value From Theme Options
          global $theme_option;
          $draft_time_integer = $theme_option['draft-time-left'];

          // Get Draft Expiration Value From Meta
          $single_draft_time_left = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'draft_time_left', true );

          // Decide If Theme Options Or Meta Draft Expiration Value
          if ( $single_draft_time_left <= 0 && $draft_time_integer <= 0 ) {
            $draft_time = 0;
          }
          else if ( $single_draft_time_left < $draft_time_integer && $single_draft_time_left > 0 || $single_draft_time_left > $draft_time_integer ) {
            $draft_time = $single_draft_time_left;
          }
          else {
            $draft_time = $draft_time_integer;
          }

          // Draft Expiration Value To Seconds
          $draft_time_seconds = $draft_time * 86400;

          // Draft Age In Seconds
          $draft_age = strtotime($time_property_modified);
          $draft_age = time() - $draft_age;

          // Calculate Draft Expiration Date
          $draft_expiration_time = date( 'H:i:s d.m.Y' ,strtotime( $time_property_modified ) + $draft_time_seconds );

          // Show Icon And Time Left Until Draft Gets Deleted In Tooltip ONLY IN SUBMIT LISTING
          if ( $draft_time && $draft_age <= $draft_time_seconds ) {
            global $post;  
            if ( is_page_template( 'template-property-submit-listing.php' ) ) { 
              return '<i class="fa fa-clock-o" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . __( 'Property gets deleted on ' . $draft_expiration_time , 'tt' ) . '"></i>';
            }
            else {
              return false;
            }
          }
          // Delete Draft If Time Is Up
          else if( $draft_time && $draft_age > $draft_time_seconds ) {

                // I got this
          }
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if I publish a post, then later change it to Draft? Does _valueX_ change or is it the first time a post is published? Your question has gaps which make a difference to how the logic needs to be written. You've also made no (visible) attempt yourself, which is usually seen as lazy with the StackOverflow community, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Im sorry if that annoys you that I didn't add my code. Last time I added it, it got ignored and said that post is too long. I'll add it right away.

Comment: That's not a reason to not paste your code. If last time people told you that your code was too long, it's maybe because you didn't provided relevant parts only.

Comment: Sorry, Im new in here, I've tried to post short/long, specific/thorough questions in all forms but my questions newer get any attention and I've never pasted pointless code that is not related to my question. Still, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: So the expected behaviour is to register the post status change date from anything to publish (the first time the post is published only), then run some cron that delete the posts where that date match the expire date from your theme options?

Comment: Yes, you got everything correct, only there is one more level in that process & that is draft. Most easiest would be to say: you publish post -> time passes (aka published post value from theme options. Example: 15 days or certain date&time) -> automatically change published post to draft -> time passes (aka draft value from theme options. Example: 30 days or certain date&time) -> automatically delete draft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) How to use WP Post Status Transitions to register exact date & time
>   of post status change (let's name it valueX)?

In my opinion the better way to handle this is not to use the Post Transition Status hooks but a [Wordpress Cron](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WP-Cron_Functions) - as the hooks will be called when the admin will change a post status. We'll just use one Post Transition Status to register **the first time the post has been published** in a custom field named `firstPublishTime`:

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'first_publish_time_register', 10, 3);
function first_publish_time_register($new, $old, $post) {
    if ($new == 'publish' && $old != 'publish' && $post->post_type == 'post') { // change this to whatever post type you like
        $firstPublishTime = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'firstPublishTime', true);
        if(empty($firstPublishTime)) {
            // First time the post is publish, register the time
            add_post_meta($post->ID, 'firstPublishTime',  strftime('%F %T'), true);
        }
    }
}
```

> 2) Now I bring other value from my theme options (valueY) - it's
>   either a period (e.g 30 days) or date & time

For the next part I'll consider that you have two theme options, both periods: one for the "publish to draft" delay named `your_theme_option1` and an other for the "draft to deleted delay" named `your_theme_option2` ; in a `YY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS` format. For exemple `00-00-30-00-00-00` will mean 30 days, `00-01-00-00-00-00` a month etc.

> 3) How to make a calculation with valueX and valueY to get valueZ ->
>   that's date & time when post deletes itself!

That's where the fun goes. We'll register a WP Cron that will execute every hour (***please note that it's not a server cron and will not be processed if no one visit your website in the hour***).
This following code will execute the `cron_postStatus()` function every hour:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'cron_postStatus_activation');
add_action('postStatus_event', 'cron_postStatus');
function cron_postStatus_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'postStatus_event');
}
```

And now the big part:

```
function cron_postStatus() {
    // Get the theme options
    $published_to_draft_delay = get_option('your_theme_option1');
    $draft_to_deleted_delay     = get_option('your_theme_option2');
    if(!$published_to_draft_delay || !$draft_to_deleted_delay) {
        return new WP_Error('broke', __('Theme options unavailable'));
    }
    $published_to_draft_delay = explode('-', $published_to_draft_delay);
    $draft_to_deleted_delay     = explode('-', $draft_to_deleted_delay);
    $published_to_draft_delay = new DateInterval(
        'P'.$published_to_draft_delay[0].'Y'.
        $published_to_draft_delay[1].'M'.
        $published_to_draft_delay[2].'D'.
        'T'.$published_to_draft_delay[3].'H'.
        $published_to_draft_delay[4].'M'.
        $published_to_draft_delay[5].'S'
    );
    $draft_to_deleted_delay     = new DateInterval(
        'P'.$draft_to_deleted_delay[0].'Y'.
        $draft_to_deleted_delay[1].'M'.
        $draft_to_deleted_delay[2].'D'.
        'T'.$draft_to_deleted_delay[3].'H'.
        $draft_to_deleted_delay[4].'M'.
        $draft_to_deleted_delay[5].'S'
    );
    $now = new DateTime();

    // Get all the unpublished posts
    $unpublished_posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'post', // change this to whatever post type you like
        'meta_key'          => 'expirationDate',
        'post_status'       => 'draft'
    ));
    while($unpublished_posts->have_posts()) {
        $unpublished_posts->the_post();
        $expirationDate = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'expirationDate', true);
        if(!empty($expirationDate)) {
            // Date comparison
            $dt = new DateTime($expirationDate);
            $dt->add($draft_to_deleted_delay);
            if($dt > $now) {
                // Expiration date reached, unpublish the post
                wp_delete_post(get_the_ID(), true);
            }
        }
    }

    // Get all the published posts
    $published_posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'post', // change this to whatever post type you like
        'meta_key'          => 'firstPublishTime'
    ));
    while($published_posts->have_posts()) {
        $published_posts->the_post();
        $first_publish = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'firstPublishTime', true);
        if(!empty($first_publish)) {
            // Date comparison
            $dt = new DateTime($first_publish);
            $dt->add($published_to_draft_delay);
            if($dt > $now) {
                // Expiration date reached, unpublish the post
                wp_transition_post_status('draft', 'publish', $published_posts->post);
                add_post_meta($post->ID, 'expirationDate',  strftime('%F %T'), true);
            }
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Here I decided to work with [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.dateinterval.php) in order to manipulate easily the expiration dates. First, we get the expiration date options from `wp_options`, build them in `DateInterval` objects then get the current time. Then we'll do two queries, one for the drafts, and one for the published posts. For the draft, we check if there is a `expirationDate` meta value, if there is and we reached the deleted time, we delete the post from the database. For published posts, we change the status to draft if we reached the expiration date, and add a custom value named `expirationDate` - this in order to make the difference between a "publish to draft" change from the cron and a change from the administration.

*Please note that this is an untested code*

### UPDATE

Here is a function that you can use to get the time left to expiration as requested:

```
function getExpirationInfos($post) {
    // Get all informations
    $first_publish = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'firstPublishTime', true);
    $expirationDate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expirationDate', true);
    if(empty($first_publish)) {
        return '';
    }
    $published_to_draft_delay = get_option('your_theme_option1');
    $draft_to_deleted_delay     = get_option('your_theme_option2')
    $published_to_draft_delay = explode('-', $published_to_draft_delay);
    $draft_to_deleted_delay     = explode('-', $draft_to_deleted_delay);
    $published_to_draft_delay = new DateInterval(
        'P'.$published_to_draft_delay[0].'Y'.
        $published_to_draft_delay[1].'M'.
        $published_to_draft_delay[2].'D'.
        'T'.$published_to_draft_delay[3].'H'.
        $published_to_draft_delay[4].'M'.
        $published_to_draft_delay[5].'S'
    );
    $draft_to_deleted_delay     = new DateInterval(
        'P'.$draft_to_deleted_delay[0].'Y'.
        $draft_to_deleted_delay[1].'M'.
        $draft_to_deleted_delay[2].'D'.
        'T'.$draft_to_deleted_delay[3].'H'.
        $draft_to_deleted_delay[4].'M'.
        $draft_to_deleted_delay[5].'S'
    );
    $now = new DateTime();

    // Calculate time left
    if($post->post_status == 'publish') {
        $dt = new DateTime($first_publish);
        $dt->add($published_to_draft_delay);
    } else {
        if(empty($expirationDate)) {
            return '';
        }
        $dt = new DateTime($expirationDate);
        $dt->add($draft_to_deleted_delay);
    }
    $et = date_diff($dt, $now);
    $expirationTimeString = (($et->y > 0) ? $et->format('y') . ' years, ' : '') .
        (($et->m > 0) ? $et->format('y') . ' months, ' : '') .
        (($et->d > 0) ? $et->format('m') . ' days, ' : '') .
        (($et->h > 0) ? $et->format('h') . ' hours, ' : '') .
        (($et->i > 0) ? $et->format('i') . ' minutes, ' : '') .
        (($et->s > 0) ? $et->format('s') . ' seconds, ' : '');
    $expirationTimeString = substr($expirationTimeString, 0, -2);


    // Return HTML
    return '<i class="fa fa-clock-o" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . __( 'Property gets deleted on', 'tt' ) . ' ' . $expirationTimeString . '"></i>';
}
```

Then in your template do `echo getExpirationInfos($post);` to display the expiration date.

Comment: **Thank you for helping out! This looks all very good & I can't wait to test & tweak it.** Few questions after reading this: 1) What will happen if nobody visits site for 1 day & next day will? Does it still makes the changes next day or skip all that day's changes?  2) How hard would it be to integrate **hours** also and check statuses once per hour? <- Would that be big performance impact for site/server?

Comment: 1) Yes changes will be made the next day, nothing will be skipped. 2) I updated my answer with full time strings - check on how the theme options / metas are changed as well as the cron call (now set to `hourly`). I don't think it'll we be too much greedy on the server, except if you really have a lot of posts. Though I would suggest to execute the cron and measure the execution time just to be sure. You can do this by printing the time at the start and at the end of the function. Let me know if you have any trouble with the integration of this script. Cheers.

Comment: Ah and if you need to be sure that the cron is executed every hours independently of your website visits, you may want to use a server cron. If so, you'll externalize this function script in a stand alone file, including _wp-config.php_ in order to have acces to WP core.

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue if there's plenty of visitors, right? Because WP core stuff sounds very complicated for me but I'll get there one way or another. I'll let you know if Im having problems. Cheers!

Comment: Yes usually the WP Cron is reliable for most tasks, personally I use server crons only for really critical features that I need to be executed at really specific times. For maintenance operations like that it should be enough.

Comment: Hi again! Could you give me an advice how to show "time left until deactivation" if published post and "time left until deletion" if draft - icons in front-end? If you look my code, you can see a line:  `return '<i class="fa fa-clock-o" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' bla-bla TIME LEFT '"></i>';` and I added function call "tt_icon_time_left();" where I wanted this icon to appear.

Comment: This should be shown in the post template page, within the loop?

Comment: Not an expert but somewhere needs to be a calculation end date - current date? Then somehow output that value..

Comment: I updated my answer, see the function `getExpirationInfos` - it return the expiration info of the post you're sending to. Again, this is an untested code so maybe you'll have to debug a bit.

Comment: I've eliminated lots of syntax errors like **.'H.'** is **.'H'.** and changed `if(empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'firstPublishTime')))` to `if(!get_post_meta($post->ID, 'firstPublishTime'))` because I got an error. Am I right? My input is currently 10 hours: 00-00-00-10-00-00 but I get an error `DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (PY10MDTHMS)` in "getExpirationInfos" after first "new Dateinterval". Shouldn't 10 be before H? Google is very general about these errors and those are a bit more complicated than syntax..

Comment: Could you check on your `published_to_draft_delay` value, before and after the explode? It seems something is wrong in the option. And my bad, it should be `if(empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'firstPublishTime', true)))` so it returns a string and not an array. I updated all get_post_meta references to add this parameter. If you see other errors feel free to edit my answer - as I told you it's an untested code, I didn't ran it so it sure could have some typos :)

Comment: Hmm, I wish I could get to that part where I fix typos. :D Same line `if(empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'firstPublishTime', true)))` same error as before: "PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context in.."

Comment: Still "DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (PY10MDTHMS)" - I don't get option right now, I hardcorded "$published_to_draft_delay = 00-00-10-00-00-00;" for purpose of testing. Could it be that you can't use negative values and need to invert it? [link to dateinterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) Ah I don't know..

Comment: I fixed few typo mistakes that made the DateInterval construct fail. Now it should be ok - just tested it and the DateInterval objects are building as expected with the updated code.